# Excel VBA User Defined Function that counts cells with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a UDF that counts the number of cells that have conditional formatting. I wrote the following sub that works like a charm:

```
Sub SumCountByConditionalFormat()
Dim cellrngi As Range
Dim cntresi As Long

cntresi = 0

Set cellrngi = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("I2:I81")

For Each i In cellrngi
    If i.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color <> 16777215 Then
    cntresi = cntresi + 1
    End If
Next i
end sub
```

and I tried to convert it to a UDF with the following code:

```
Function CountCellsByColor1(rData As Range) As Long
Dim cntRes As Long

Application.Volatile
cntRes = 0
For Each cell In rData
    If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color <> 16777215 Then
        cntRes = cntRes + 1
    End If
Next cell

CountCellsByColor1 = cntRes
End Function
```

However when I try the UDF i get a #VALUE! returned. I'm really not sure why and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.DisplayFormat

Comment: @SJR thanks! unfortunately now instead of #VALUE! i'm getting a 0.

Comment: Just removing `DisplayFormat` from the code gave me the correct value when testing the function.
Make sure the right cells are selected and run calculations with `F9` to update the cell

Comment: I'm in excel 2010 and using Power Query. Do you think that might be causing the error?

Comment: You can always use your CF criteria in the function.

Comment: Why not just count by the same criteria that is used to format the cells in the first place? Seems like you are using a middle man here.

Comment: It's very old post but someone might find this useful: Check Relative references in formula which is pulling the data or used evaluation of CF. Create a NamedRange with this formula like "GetData". Now you can use this to populate data or use it in if condition as it will always evaluate to true or false for CF. eg. =if(GetData,"It's true","Nothing here")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can work around the inability to access `DisplayFormat` in a UDF using `Evaluate`

```
Function DFColor(c As Range)
    DFColor = c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Function


Function CountCellsByColor1(rData As Range) As Long
    Dim cntRes As Long, clr As Long, cell As Range
    cntRes = 0
    For Each cell In rData.Cells
        'Evaluate the formula string in the context of the
        '  worksheet hosting rData
        clr = rData.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(" & cell.Address() & ")")
        If clr <> 16777215 Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    CountCellsByColor1 = cntRes
End Function
```