# Custom VBA Function keeps returning #VALUE

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to the VBA Function and I wrote a very simple function to test if the background of a cell is filled with a particular color. However, the return value is always ***#VALUE!***. It should be a very simple mistake but still can't find where the problem is after I tried different methods to fix it. I attached the code I wrote below. Can anybody help me with my problem?

Thanks

```
Function SAFETY(Cell As Range) As Boolean
Application.Volatile
If (Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = 7040761) Then
SAFETY = True
Else
SAFETY = False
End If
End Function
```

Update:

I checked the formula with the Insert Function section under Formulas Tab, the return value is actually TRUE. However, it just cannot displayed on the worksheet cell. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzBXS.png)

Updates 2:

I tried Tim Williams solutions and the codes are attached as follow

```
Public Function SAFETY(Cell As Range) As Boolean
Application.Volatile
Dim clr As Long
clr = Application.Evaluate("GetDFColor(""" & _
Cell.Parent.Name & """,""" & Cell.Address() & """)")
If (clr = 7040761) Then
SAFETY = True
Else
SAFETY = False
End If
End Function
```

And

```
Public Function SAFETY(Cell As Range) As Boolean
Application.Volatile
Dim clr As Long
clr = Cell.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(""" & Cell.Address() & """)")
If (clr = 7040761) Then
SAFETY = True
Else
SAFETY = False
End If
End Function
```

But still can't get it right.

Comment: Try `Cell.Interior.Color`. Also I am assuming that these colors are not generated via conditional formatting

Comment: [Range.Interior property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.interior)

Comment: Hi, Siddharth, Thanks for your reply, I am actually using the conditional formattng for  the worksheet cells so I afraid Cell.Interior.Color wont work

Comment: DisplayFormat isn't accessible from a UDF

Comment: So If I wanted to check if a conditional formatting is filled with a particular color, hw should I do that?

Comment: See @TimWilliams answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753141/excel-vba-user-defined-function-that-counts-cells-with-conditional-formatting) :P

Comment: If that quesiton doesn't answers your question then let me know and I will reopen this question.

Comment: I tried Tim's answer however the display is still #VALUE! for some reason. @Siddharth Rout

Comment: can you update the question with the code that you are trying?

Comment: I just updated the codes I tried yesterday, I searched online for similar questions and found that UDF limits the conditional formattiong cells. Maybe I should find another way to work it out.