# Count Conditionally Formatted Cells if Colored

Tags: vba, user-defined-functions, conditional-formatting

I am trying to write a function to count cells that have been colored due to a conditional format. UDF can't use the DisplayFormat property, so Tim Williams wrote this brilliant solution below. It works great when I initally input the function into the cell. However, when I change a value in one of the cells it is pointing to, then the function reports 0. I then have to re-enter the function to make it answer correctly.

Does someone know why this is happening? And how to fix it?

```
Function DFColor(addr As String)
    DFColor = Range(addr).DisplayFormat.Interior.color
End Function


Function CountColoredCells(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim count As Long, color As Long, cell As Range
    count = 0
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        color = rng.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(""" & cell.Address() & """)")
        If color <> 16777215 Then       '16777215 is the blank color value
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    CountColoredCells = count
End Function
```

Here is the link to his post with the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54757688/7053791

Comment: It's better to actually count based on the *logic* of the Conditional Format rule, instead of this approach.

Comment: ^ this is the way to go. You are just using conditional formatting as a middle man when you can just work directly with the logic. i.e. recreate your conditional formatting logic in VBA. Just realized I left the same comment on your original question ha

Comment: That approach may be better in most cases, but not in my case. In my particular case having a function is the best approach, and I need conditional formatting for the user interface of my worksheet.

Just so you know I have 23 different conditional format rules across 19 columns. I'm not going to write that _logic_ in VBA. It's already accounted for in the ocnditional formats. The approach above works great. I just need it to automatically update when a cell is changed. That's the goal of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in this design:

```
Function DFColor(addr As String)
    DFColor = Range(addr).DisplayFormat.Interior.color
End Function
```

The cell address is passed as a string and then turned into a range object using `Range()`, but since `Range()` (in a regular code module) defaults to the ActiveSheet, if the sheet with the conditional formatting is not the ActiveSheet you will get wrong results (hence the zero you are seeing).

This is more robust - pass in an actual Range and use that directly:

```
Function DFColor(c As Range)
    DFColor = c.DisplayFormat.Interior.color
End Function

Function CountColoredCells(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim count As Long, color As Long, cell As Range
    count = 0
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        color = rng.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(" & cell.Address() & ")") '<<EDITED
        If color <> 16777215 Then       '16777215 is the blank color value
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    CountColoredCells = count
End Function
```

I've edited the version at the linked post

Comment: That did solve the zero issue, thank you! However, it still is not updating upon a change, unless I click into the formula box and press enter, or re-drag the cell down. Formulas are on automatic calculate.

Comment: Using application.volatile makes it so I only need to click enter in one of the cells to make it auto calculate everything. But I'm still hoping for something that just makes it autocalculate by itself upon any changes.

Comment: I ended up using solution #2 from this post - https://superuser.com/a/1261461 .
However, it only works when I update sheet the function is on. I actually often change things in other sheets that affect the value the function outputs, so I need it to update on any change to any worksheet. Any ideas?

I like the optional variant solution with Now() because it only recalculates that UDF every time something is changed. I'd like to avoid a solution that recalulates every formula in my workbook with every change as that would be very expensive.

Comment: I'd expect it to update if the cells in the input range are updating.  If the cells have CF linked to some other range(s) though, the formula won't update.  You could make it automatic if you added a range parameter for the cells whose values are changing.