# Determine if a range of cells have the same color with and without conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of cells that I need to determine if all the cells in the same row are the same color. If they are I need to return a result such as "Match" otherwise "No Match". The problem is that some of the cells are conditionally formatted based on a selection list while the others are colored based on the color fill selection. The problem I'm having is that the actual background color of the cells with conditional formatting doesn't change so the formula I used doesn't return the same results for the CF and non-CF cells.

Here's the code I use to return the cell color code but the code is different for the cells with conditional formatting:

```
Function InteriorColor(CellColor As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    InteriorColor = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

I need a formula because the worksheet I need to apply this to is updated weekly and there may be additional columns and rows added in the future.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753141/excel-vba-user-defined-function-that-counts-cells-with-conditional-formatting) to determine the color applied by conditional formatting. Also, you probably want to use `Color`, not `ColorIndex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
Function DFColor(c As Range)
    DFColor = c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Function

Function checkColor(rData As Range) As Variant
    Dim clrSto As Long, clr As Long, cell As Range
    clrSto = rData.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(" & rData.Cells(1).Address() & ")")

    For Each cell In rData.Cells
        clr = rData.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(" & cell.Address() & ")")

        If clr <> clrSto Then
            checkColor = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell
    checkColor = True
End Function
```

Tested on this dataset, where column F is colored via Conditional Formatting:

[image: Use case application]

**EDIT**

To define your own color you want to check, this should work, you just need to type the color in Hex as a second argument to the function:

```
Function checkColorV2(rData As Range, Optional hexColor As String) As Variant
    Dim temp(1 To 3) As String, clrSto As Long, clr As Long, cell As Range
    
    If hexColor = "" Then
        clrSto = rData.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(" & rData.Cells(1).Address() & ")")
    Else
        temp(1) = Left(hexColor, 2)
        temp(2) = Mid(hexColor, 3, 2)
        temp(3) = Right(hexColor, 2)
        hexColor = temp(3) & temp(2) & temp(1)
        clrSto = WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(hexColor)
    End If
        
    For Each cell In rData.Cells
        clr = rData.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(" & cell.Address() & ")")
        If clr <> clrSto Then
            checkColorV2 = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell
    checkColorV2 = True
End Function
```

Here you can see it tested:

[image: Test of v2]

Comment: Thanks for your response. This works as explained. I do have one question though. If I wanted to check to make sure that all the cells were one color, for example Green, how would I change the code. So if all cells are green on a row then True otherwise False. Thanks.

Comment: @matt you didn't specify exactly *how* you declare this Green color, so I added a second argument to the function where you input the color you want to check in hexcode and behaves as the original when left empty

Comment: If I need to check the range of cells to determine if they are all one of two colors (Green or Grey) how would I do that? I tried adding to my formula but it's returning TRUE even if there are other colors such as white in the range.                                             
 
        clrSto = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        clrSto2 = RGB(191, 191, 191)

            If clr <> clrSto  or clr <> clrSto2 Then
                checkColor = False     Thanks for your help.

Comment: first you need an array variable: `dim arr as variant`, then you need to store those two or more colors in that array: `arr = array(clrSto, clrSto2)`. Finally, match and check for errors: `If IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(clr, arr, 0))`. Untested, but I guess it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help Fernando. That worked perfectly. I was also able to get what I needed by tweaking your original code using the RGB color format:

```
Function DFColor(c As Range)
    DFColor = c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Function

Function checkColor(rData As Range) As Variant
    Dim clrSto As Long, clr As Long, cell As Range
'   clrSto = rData.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(" & rData.Cells(1).Address() & 
")")
    clrSto = RGB(0, 176, 80)

    For Each cell In rData.Cells
        clr = rData.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(" & cell.Address() & ")")

        If clr <> clrSto Then
            checkColor = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell
    checkColor = True
End Function
```