# User Defined Function to identify columns with coloured cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a user defined function. I have a workbook with columns which have some cells coloured grey and I want to create a summary row at the top, so if the first column has any grey cells then cell A1 should be TRUE, if not then leave cell A1 blank.

The code I've got so far for my function is:

```
Public Function IsColor(currCol As Range) As Boolean
    Dim currCell As Range
    
    For Each currCell In currCol
        If currCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then
            IsColor = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next currCell
    
End Function
```

But this is returning #VALUE! when I use the function in my workbook and I don't understand why?

Thanks

Comment: [Displayformat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat) does not work in UDFs. Specified in the first paragraph under the first code block in the link.

Comment: [Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753141/excel-vba-user-defined-function-that-counts-cells-with-conditional-formatting).

Comment: There are workarounds but surely better to use the CF criteria.

Comment: Thanks, that's it working just by removing DisplayFormat. It hadn't occurred to me that UDFs might have different rules than subs!