# How can I retrieve the background color of a conditionally formatted cell?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, conditional-formatting

I am trying to find the background color of a cell that is conditionally formatted.  The Defined FUnction code is below, it works if I manually shade a cell, but if the conditional formatting is applied it returns a code as if the cell had a standard white background.

I am trying to use this function to apply additional conditional formatting based off of that background color.

```
Function IdentifyColor(CellToTest As range)

'Returns R + (256 * G) + (65536 * B)
'IdentifyColor = 255 for red, 65280 for green, etc.
IdentifyColor = CellToTest.Interior.ColorIndex

End Function
```

Here is what the sheet looks like with both manual and conditionally formatted cells and the return values:

[image: Color Formatting]

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753141/excel-vba-user-defined-function-that-counts-cells-with-conditional-formatting) perhaps. First, conditional formatting would be `CellToTest.DisplayFormat.Interior...`, but UDF's and conditional formatting don't play nicely together. Though...."I am trying to use this function to apply additional conditional formatting based off of that background color." sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Don't test for the color. Test using the same formula you used to color them in the first place. It's more explicit this way and cuts out a middle operator thus a point of failure

Comment: May I please know why you want to find the background colour? maybe there is a workaround...

Comment: @TerryW I am trying to setup this worksheet so that if there is a 4 week break in sales then all four blank cells are highlighted.  I currently have conditional formatting to check for the previous four weeks and then that cell is highlighted, I basically want to add a second conditional format formula that says 'If the cell below you is this color, then you should also be that color' which i why I am trying to get a UDF to return the value of the background color.