# Why is my count cells by color code not working?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code to count cells by color, however it is not counting correctly. Can anyone help me with this code? I cannot find out why it is not counting the cells correctly.

-Thanks in advance :)

```
Function GetColorCount(CountRange As Range, CountColor As Range)
Dim CountColorValue As Integer
Dim TotalCount As Integer
CountColorValue = CountColor.Interior.ColorIndex
Set rCell = CountRange
For Each rCell In CountRange
    If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = CountColorValue Then
        TotalCount = TotalCount + 1
    End If
Next rCell
GetColorCount = TotalCount
End Function
```

Comment: Is the color applied manually or via conditional formatting? What does "not counting correctly" mean specifically?

Comment: via conditional formatting. By not counting correctly I mean, that when I apply the function it counts almost double what the actual count should be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753141/excel-vba-user-defined-function-that-counts-cells-with-conditional-formatting. `.Interior.ColorIndex` or `.Interior.Color` are separate from Conditional Formatting, which is `.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex`.

Comment: But really, instead of using VBA here, just replicate the conditional formatting logic in a COUNTIFS formula if possible.

Comment: HI BigBen, Thanks for the answer. I am unsure how to replicate the conditional formatting logic as you say above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the details of the conditional formatting rule?

Comment: If a cell is >.5 then add a color. And I have it set to all the colmns of my spreadsheet, maybe that's why. There is more than 10 conditions.

Comment: Use COUNTIFS to count all the cells with a value greater than .5.