# Know if the cell is colored or not

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have multiple columns where I did conditional formatting (colors), based on certain statistics formula.

I am trying to create an AND statement for every row, where it is:
TRUE - if all the column colors in that row is green
FALSE - if at least one is false.

I am stuck at getting the color information from the cell. I followed this Youtube video, and a bunch of other articles, however I came up negative.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeUrO7YENSg

Any suggestions on getting the color of a "Conditionally formatted Cell"?

Formula used on each column is the following: (where the value of FLAG changes based on the column. Most of the times FLAG = 1 or 1.5)

```
=AND(B5>=AVERAGE(B$5:B$33)-FLAG*STDEV.S(B$5:B$33),B5<= AVERAGE(B$5:B$33)+FLAG*STDEV.S(B$5:B$33))
```

Using 8 times this formula on one cell, with AND condition, would be the very cumbersome and prone to mistakes. So that's why I opted for conditional formatting.

Comment: Don't try to get the color of a cell, instead recreate the logic of the formula. What is the formula you used?

Comment: I updated the question. I cant use the formula, as there are like 8 columns, and the formula is different in each column.

Comment: Sure you can, you can use `AND` with a separate condition for each column. What version of Excel btw?

Comment: Thats a biggest formula Ben - should not there be any efficient way? Excel version 2016

Comment: If it's easier, use 8 helper columns, one for each condition, and then `AND` their results together in the 9th column. Or move the average and standard deviation calcs into separate cells and reference those cells.

Comment: [VBA alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753141/excel-vba-user-defined-function-that-counts-cells-with-conditional-formatting), if you're desperate. Or you can easily write a `Sub` to count the colored cells in a row. But there is no native formulaic approach to check if conditional formatting is true, w/o recreating the conditional formatting logic. Or maybe [this](https://exceljet.net/blog/test-conditional-formatting-with-dummy-formulas) is inspiration.