# Problems with conditional formating and counting of colored cells after that

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, conditional-formatting

I have created UDF that counts colored cells. But it counts only that cells that are colored manually. For example my conditional formatting have colored 5 of 10 cells and my UDF formula (=COUNTIFCOLOUR(AD2;B2:Y2)) shows me 0, but when I color manually 2 other cells with same color, then UDF shows me the result 2. Why is this happening? Any suggestions? It looks like it ignores conditional formatting color...

This is my UDF:

```
Function COUNTIFCOLOUR(Colour As Range, rng As Range) As Long
Dim NoCells As Long
Dim CellColour As Long
Dim rngCell As Range
CellColour = Colour.Interior.Color
For Each rngCell In rng
    If rngCell.Interior.Color = CellColour Then
        NoCells = NoCells + 1
    End If
Next
COUNTIFCOLOUR = NoCells
End Function
```

Comment: You can't use a UDF like this without a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753141/excel-vba-user-defined-function-that-counts-cells-with-conditional-formatting). But really, you should replicate the *logic* of the conditional format, and not depend on color.

Comment: to get the conditional formatting color one would use [Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat)  But as @BigBen stated it does not work in Functions called by the worksheet without some hacky work around.